# Is it possible to search two different tables in sql that are not linked?

Tags: sql

I have two separate sql tables for an assignment about nutrition, one including all liquid and data related to the liquid, and one for solids. These tables are not linked, so I was wondering if there was a way to search both tables from a user input without them being linked, or if they needed to be put into one table altogether. I know there are Join statements but have not found one that I think relates to my situation (I could be wrong though).

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for `union all`:

```
select . . . 
from liquids
where . . .
union all
select . . .
from solids
where . . .
```

The major caveat is that the column lists for the two `select`s need to be compatible -- same number of columns, same types.

In general, it is a bad sign when two tables in a database have the same columns.  If this is the case, then it is better to have one column in the database, perhaps with a column that distinguishes "liquids" from "solids".

Comment: Thankyou for that! Yeah it's a stupid assignment requirement to have a certain amount of tables and the website I'm 'proposing' to make doesn't really have a need for that many tables so I've had to split liquids and solids.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 different tables

`UNION ALL` operator can help you to solve your query

```
SELECT x1, x2,.. FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT x1, x2,.. FROM table2
```